# Extracting a variable from a formula

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract the response variable from a formula, even if that formula contains a function?

```
x1 <- ~responsename

as.character(x1[[2]])

x2 <- ~log(responsename)

as.character(x2[[2]][[2]])
```

Both of these approaches give the desired answer (`"responsename"`). But is there a way to get the same answer in *either* case, automatically?

ps: assuming that the formula is always `~ responsename` or `~ f(responsename)`, no `+` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tail(all.names(x1),1)
```

seems to do what you want. e.g.

```
tail(all.names(x2),1)
#[1] "responsename"
tail(all.names(x1),1)
#[1] "responsename"
tail(all.names(~sin(responsename)),1)
#[1] "responsename"
tail(all.names(~(responsename)^2),1)
#[1] "responsename"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your terminology is non-standard (=wrong!).

The (usually) single "response variable" (aka "dependent variable") is on the left of the tilde `~`.

The (often) multiple variables on the right of the tilde are known as "explanatory" or "predictor" or "independent" variables.

Your examples are of one sided formulae with no response variable.

You can use `all.vars()` to get variable names; @Miff, `all.names()` returns function names as well.

I guess where there is a response variable it will usually be the first so you could use `all.vars(formula)[1]`, but where (like your examples) it is a one sided formula with no response this will give the first explanatory variable.

Better is to identify the response variable with `attr(terms(formula), "response")`

```
f <- y ~ x1 + x2
all.vars(f)[attr(terms(f), "response")]
# [1] "y"
f <- y ~ sin(x1) + cos(x2)
all.vars(f)[attr(terms(f), "response")]
# [1] "y"
f <- ~ x1 + x2
all.vars(f)[attr(terms(f), "response")]
# character(0)
f <- log(y) ~ x1 + x2
all.vars(f)[attr(terms(f), "response")]
# [1] "y"
```

If you really want the (last specified) explanatory variable then you can use `tail(all.vars(formula),1)`

Comment: You're quite right, formulae are usually used to express statistical models. Certainly, `terms()` returns an object with a "response" attribute, which is on the left side. However, this is only one use of formulae. You might be interested to know that they have a more general use in R, which is to capture an expression and its environment. See for example http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html

Comment: Are you trying to say that your use of the term "response variable" is in any way standard?